# ReferenceError: WebhookClient is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

пишу бота на node.js, выдаёт ошибку `ReferenceError: WebhookClient is not defined`
помогите, вот полный код:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const {
  CommandInteraction,
  Permissions,
  MessageEmbed,
  Message,
} = require("discord.js");

// Database queries
const Guild = require("../../models/Report/report");

// Configs
const emojis = require("../../../Controller/emojis/emojis");

module.exports.cooldown = {
  length: 108000000 /* in ms */,
  users: new Set(),
};

/**
 * Runs the command.
 * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction The Command Interaciton
 * @param {any} utils Additional util
 */
module.exports.run = async (interaction, utils) => {
  try {
    const target = interaction.options.getMember("target");
    const reason = interaction.options.getString("reason");

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${emojis.notify} Report`)
      .setDescription(
        `Пользователь: ${interaction.user.tag}\nНарушитель: ${target.user.tag} (${target.id}).\nПричина: **${reason}**`
      )
      .setThumbnail(interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
      .setFooter({
        text: `С: ${interaction.user.tag}`,
        iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
      })
      .setColor("RED")
      .setTimestamp();

    const guildQuery = await Guild.findOne({ id: interaction.guild.id });
    if (!guildQuery) {
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `${emojis.error} | Этот сервер не имеет систему репортов.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });
    }

    if (target.id === interaction.guild.ownerId)
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `${emojis.error} | Я не могу зарепортить овнера.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    if (
      target.roles.highest.position >=
      interaction.guild.me.roles.highest.position
    )
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `${emojis.error} | Я не могу зарепорить участника, роль которого выше моей.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    if (target.id === interaction.user.id)
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `${emojis.error} | Ты не можешь зарепортить себя.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    if (target.id === interaction.guild.me.id)
      return interaction.reply({
        content: `${emojis.error} | Я не могу зарепортить себя.`,
        ephemeral: true,
      });

    if (guildQuery) {
      const webhookid = guildQuery.webhookid;
      const webhooktoken = guildQuery.webhooktoken;

      const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({
         id: webhookid,
         token: webhooktoken,
      });

        webhookClient.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
    interaction.reply({
      content: `${emojis.success} | Успешно зарепорчен ${target} по причине: ${reason}`,
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};

module.exports.permissions = {
  clientPermissions: [Permissions.FLAGS.SEND_MESSAGES],
  userPermissions: [Permissions.FLAGS.SEND_MESSAGES],
};

module.exports.data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("report")
  .setDescription("Репорт на пользователя для админов")
  .addUserOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName("target")
      .setDescription("Укажи пользователя, на которого подаёшь репорт.")
      .setRequired(true)
  )
  .addStringOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName("reason")
      .setDescription("Опиши причину репорта, и залей пруфы на imgur.")
      .setRequired(true)
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема возникла из-за отсутствия `WebhookClient` в вашем коде. Так как Вы используете `discord.js`, то достаточно добавить `WebhookClient` в объект на 2-7 строчках вашего кода:

```js
const {
  CommandInteraction,
  Permissions,
  MessageEmbed,
  Message,
  WebhookClient,  // <------------------
} = require("discord.js");
```